# Is there any way to make same thing without jQuery, and using only CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to web design, and specially to technologies like css3 and html5,
I want to built a website that will use as much as possible CSS3 and HTML5 and as less as possible JavaScript.

So I want to get pretty much the same behavior using only CSS/HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wrapper section").click(function() {
        var bcn = $(this).next('.box-content');
        if ($('.box-content').is(':visible')) {
            $('.box-content').hide();
            bcn.show();
        }
        else {
            $('.box-content').hide();
            bcn.slideToggle(200);
        }
    });
});
```

That's what I want to make without JS: http://jsfiddle.net/8BLD7/7/

Comment: I don't think that CSS3 can replace that logic you have there.
Notice that the title and your question don't match. One thing is not using jQuery and another is not using JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript is what allows you to take static CSS and HTML and make it dynamic. You have here onLoad events, click events, DOM selectors, conditional statements and animations with specific durations, all working in conjunction. You'll HAVE to use some level of JavaScript to get the results you are looking for.

Comment: JavaScript is the right tool when you want *behaviour*.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about some `transition` property or something similar. But If you guys say it's impossible, I believe you =)

Comment: Not to be a downer but using `as much as possible CSS3 and HTML5` may not be the best idea. Not all browsers support all the features of CSS3 and HTML5. You risk producing a site where features are scattered around the browsers that support them. You may want to try the strategy of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) which builds off the basics of current browsers and adds new functionality for the browsers that support it. That way you don't end up with a site that has partial functionality across all the browsers. Just a thought...

Comment: @Vor No problem. Glad it'll work for you. I'll move it down as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly approximate to the code you have there, obviously as others have stated this will only work in modern browsers—I wouldn't recommend purely using this system—but it is something that can be worked in as a progressive enhancement as mentioned by War10ck.

http://jsfiddle.net/3VQ9X/

For futher information on how this works, and the issues to be aware of read these links:

- http://css-tricks.com/on-target/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/stay-on-target

Here's the markup and css involved.

**markup**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <h3><a href="#content-1">App 1</a><h3>
    <h3><a href="#content-2">App 2</a><h3>
  </nav>
  <section class="main">
    <section class="box-content" id="content-1">
      <p> This is content 1 </p>
    </section>
    <section class="box-content" id="content-2">
      <p> This is content 2 </p>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

**css (basic element setup, can be modified as you like)**

```
nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

section.main {
  position: relative; /* this is important */
  overflow: hidden; /* as is this, but everthing else can be modified */
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px; /* having fixed dimensions will make things easier */
  height: 500px;
}
```

**css (the magic bit)**

```
section.box-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-500px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,-500px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-500px);
  -o-transform: translate(0,-500px);
  transform: translate(0,-500px);
}

/* the pseudo selector :target only comes into effect when
   an anchored link has been clicked that targets a specific
   element by id. If the element with the id has this pseudo
   selector applied, then the css will be applied. Tie this
   together with transformations, and you have interactive 
   dynamic css :) */

section.box-content:target {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
  -o-transform: translate(0,0);
  transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This look very similar to what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Vor no problem, hope it helps. You should definitely still follow the advice from War10ck however... with great power comes great... urm, something or other.

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers support all the features of `CSS3` and `HTML5`. You run the risk of producing a site where features are scattered around the browsers that support them.

You may want to try the strategy of:

[progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)

which builds off the basics of current browsers and adds new functionality for the browsers that support it. That way you don't end up with a site that has partial functionality across all the browsers.

Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

War10ck is correct. However if you wish to use CSS3 and HTML5 either way, you can check out the `CSS3 :target Selector`. The `:target` pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the URL and the id of an element are the same.

You can find more information about it at http://css-tricks.com/on-target.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/_omi/yDWzA/6/